# How to create a two columns layout with gap

Tags: css

I have two columns in my div and I want to separate them with a gap represented by a vertical line like this:

[image]

How can I achieve that?

Comment: What did you already try?

Comment: You can use this link: https://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_multiple_columns.asp

Comment: Simple: create 2 divs inside the main div and set main div to display: flex and the insiders to position: relative

Comment: Hi Mit94, when asking a question you should add some code showing what have you tried, so other users whiling to help can help to fix _your code_, instead of making the code for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Css columns sounds like what you're looking for. You can use the column-rule property for the vertical line.

```
columns: 2 400px;
column-rule: 1px solid black;
```

https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/c/column-rule/

Please note that the order of your elements will be like a text flow, so:

```
1 | 4
2 | 5
3 | 6
```

If that doesn't work out for you, you could add a right border to your first column and add margin + padding on the right side to space it out evenly. (combined with either `display: block;` with a float, or a `display: inline-block;` for displaying the columns next to each other).